# How to save .pdf file from server to client side?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, client-server

I need some suggestion about how to save .pdf file from server to client side. I'm using C# console application to generate pdf file and save in server local c and I manage to do it by using .ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, report). Now I need to save the file to client side rather than save in server local c because my user aren't allowed to access the server. Appreciate if someone can help me about this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to export to a UNC path which the users can access. Don't forget your console application will have to run as a user with write access to the UNC path.